# SQL Anywhere to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlanywhere

I've been trying to migrate a SQLAnywhere database to SQL Server without success. The best I have been able to do is use MySQL workbench to migrate from SQL Anywhere to MySQL and then use MS migration tool to go from MySQL to SQL Server. The problem is that I get many errors. The database has almost 2000 tables and in the conversion from SQL Anywhere to MySQL I get errors migrating 150 of them.

I wonder if there is a more direct approach, also I know MS has a SAP ASE to SQL Migration tool but haven't been able to figure out how to import the SQL Anywhere into ASE and SAP's documentation is pretty much useless.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try migrate to MySql instead of MS Sql, it might be a easier approach. Migrating tables is just the begining, you will need to migrate the queries, stored procedures, functions etc.

Some of my legacy code based used a lot of "natual join" which is not supported by MSSQL, and luckily is availbe in MySQL. 
I can't imagin how many lines of code you need to change for 2000 tables.

Comment: Don't need to migrate stored procedures, queries, functions or anything else, just need to extract the data in the tables but we work with SQL Server only and the data was handled to us in a SQL anywhere reload script. Problem being that the number of tables is huge and so is the number of rows in each table. So I get a lot of overflow errors.

Comment: @cadash I'm not familiar with SQL Anywhere, but have you tried moving the data with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)?

Comment: @HardCode Thanks! I currently have SQL Server Express, will download the developer edition, give it a try and let you know. Thanks a bunch mate